# Подгрузка постов из определенной категории

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

у меня есть функция load more и как сделать, чтобы она именно подгружала те посты из категории на которой я нахожусь, а не со всего post_type мне выводила посты. Вот мой код:

```
   <div class="page" id="ajax-posts">
                            <?php
                            $term = get_queried_object();
                            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 0;
                            $postsPerPage = 6;
                            $postOffset = $paged * $postsPerPage;
                            $args = array(
                               'post_type' => 'faqs',
                               'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                               'offset' => $postOffset,
                               'tax_query' => array(
                                  array(
                                     'taxonomy' => 'taxn',
                                     'field' => 'slug',
                                     'terms' => $term->slug
                                  )
                               ),
                            );
                            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                            if ($loop->have_posts()) {
                               while ($loop->have_posts()) {
                                  $loop->the_post();
                                  get_template_part('template-parts/post');
                               }
                            }
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                            ?>
                         </div>
                         <a href="#!" id="load-more" class="btn">Load more </a>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
             var ppp = 6;
             var pageNumber = 1;
    
             var cat_id = '<?php echo $term->slug; ?>';
     
             function load_posts() {
                pageNumber++;
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "html",
                   url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                   data: {
                      action: 'more_post_ajax',
                      pageNumber: pageNumber,
                   },
                   success: function(data) {
                      var $data = $(data);
                      if ($data.length) {
                         $("#ajax-posts").append($data);
                         $("#load-more").attr("disabled", false);
    
                      } else {
                         $("#load-more").hide();
                      }
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      console.log('Error')
                   }
                });
                return false;
             }
             $("#load-more").on("click", function(e) {
                $("#load-more").attr("disabled", true);
                load_posts();
             });
          });
       </script>
<?php
function more_post_ajax()
{
    $ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 6;
    $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;
    $postOffset = $page * $ppp;
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $cat_name = $term->name;
    header("Content-Type: text/html");
    $args = array(
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'post_type' => 'faqs',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged'    => $page,
        'category_name' => $cat_name,
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($loop->have_posts()) :  while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/post');
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
?>
```

Comment: Ну наверное не мешало бы передать `cat_id` который Вы определяете выше Вашего ajax, вы же для чего-то это делаете, верно? Затем обработать и подставить куда нужно это значение, так как `get_queried_object()` не будет работать внутри функции `more_post_ajax()`, потому и выводятся все записи.

Comment: @Simon Спасибо за ответ. Я передавал cat_id во внутрь $.ajax data после pageNumber вставлял category: cat_id, но ничего не изменялось, если get_queried_object()  не работает внутри , то что мне нужно объявить внутри функции more_post_ajax(), чтобы возвращались только текущие посты из категории?

Comment: Вы же там получаете данные при помощи `$_POST`, таким образом можете получить и category. Или так же как Вы делали `$_POST['category']`, а лучше всего используя фильтр, например `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)`.

Comment: @Simon Внутри функции ```more_post_ajax()``` я уже обращался к ```$_POST['category']``` и передавал в ```category_name``` значение, но опять ничего не вышло. Сейчас я попробовал через ```filter_input``` , но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Ну да, сравните два своих `WP_Query`, разницы не замечаете? Почему в первом Вы используете `'taxonomy' => 'taxn'`, а во втором `category_name`? Используя `category_name` Вы пытаетесь получить записи из [категории (рубрики)](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#categories), а не из кастомной таксономии. Просто Ви когда приводите свой код в пример, предполагается что Вы +/- понимаете что там происходит.

Comment: "Сейчас я попробовал через filter_input , но ничего не изменилось." -- [filter_input](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.sanitize.php) с очищающим фильтром `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` используется для фильтрации и очистки данных которые Вы передаете посредством аякс запроса, это никак не влияет на конкретно вывод записей.

Comment: @Simon Спасибо, что отвечаете,  Я пробовал добавить в функцию ```more_post_ajax``` в запрос WP_Query ```tax_query``` определенную категорию и таксономию свою. то посты будут показываться правильные. но как сделать. чтобы оно динамично работало? Извините, если я что-то не улавливаю, что Вы пытаетесь сказать. Спасибо, еще раз.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139821/discussion-between-simon-and-).